# How to achieve mouse hover particle effect like below?

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I have achieve the above solution on mouse over the particles effect three.js but there is a problem i am encountering whereby if you move the position of the object or resize the canvas the mouse hover on the object is not staying with the 3D object but on the screen width. Is there a way to achieve themouse over effect to stay always on top of the object.

[image]

As you can see my mouse is in the middle and the object position is:

```
    var objectDir = themeDir + '/glb/Arrows_007.glb';
        var loader = new GLTFLoader();
        loader.load(objectDir, function(object) {
            var model = object.scene.children[0];

            let mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xff2266,
                wireframe: true,
                transparent: true,
                opacity: 1
            });
            model.material = mat;

            let sampler = new MeshSurfaceSampler(model)
                .setWeightAttribute(null)
                .build();
            let pts = [];

            let n = new THREE.Vector3();
            for (let i = 0; i < MAX_POINTS; i++) {
                p = new THREE.Vector3();
                sampler.sample(p, n);
                p.destination = {
                    x: p.x,
                    y: p.y,
                    z: p.z
                };

                pts.push(p);

            }

            var pointsMat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
                size: 1,
                color: 0xE4AC25,
                sizeAttenuation: false
            });

            geometry = new THREE.Geometry().setFromPoints(pts);
            particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, pointsMat);

            cloudObject = new THREE.Object3D();
            cloudObject.add(particles);
            cloudObject.position.x = 150;
            cloudObject.position.y = 80;

            scene.add(cloudObject);

            animate();

        });

        /* GEOMETRY */

        camera.position.set(0, 0, 600);
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

        var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 0);

        var mouse = new THREE.Vector3();

        window.addEventListener("mousemove", event => {
            mouse.x = (event.clientX / $('canvas').width()) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = -(event.clientY / $('canvas').height()) * 2 + 1;

            // geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
            raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
            // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
            var hover = raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, uniforms.mouse.value);
            cloudObject.worldToLocal(hover);
        });
```

The over effect is appearing while in the middle of the screen and not when mouse is over the object, is there a way to put the hover exactly on the object, wherever the position might be and however the canvas size is?

Kindly let me know.

Thank you

Comment: @prisoner849 - might you be knowing, as you made the fiddle :) ?

Comment: Would be better to provide your code, not mine :) One option, why you've got such a result, is that you don't convert the point of intersection into object's local space. For example with `object.worldToLocal(uniforms.mouse.value)`

Comment: Hi @prisoner849, im abit new to three.js, learning it and making progress, but have looked at what you sent on worldToLocal and its working!!!! :) :) :), Thank you very much.
Are you able to explain where i went wrong?, ive edited my code above and put the whole one. 
Thank you again.